# want to use the textbox values in viewpage in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have textboxes named mark1,mark2 etc and when I press a button I want to get the sum of these values and display the result in a textbox in the view pages in cakephp

How can I get this result in the view ?

Comment: post the values in controller, make sum , return it on view and display it

Comment: You can calculate the sum with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In test.ctp file.

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('ModelName'); 

echo $this->Form->input('mark1');

echo $this->Form->input('mark2');

echo $this->Form->input('total');

echo $this->Form->Submit(__('Submit'));

echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

In Controller test Action.

```
<?php
public function test() {
if ($this->request->isPost()) {
   $this->request->data['ModelName']['total'] = $this->request->data['ModelName']['mark1'] + $this->request->data['ModelName']['mark2'];
}
?>
```

Comment: please let me know if any trubble in above code. glad to help you :)